# How can I create a reusable navbar across multiple HTML pages with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

*I would prefer a strictly JavaScript way of doing this if possible. Not really wanting to introduce a JavaScript framework into my project.*

```
Layout:
 ./index.html
 ./about.html
 ./crew.html
 ./flights.html
 ./events.html
```

I want every page to have the same navbar such that I don't have to repeat myself and fix every page every time the order of the links change.

Here's my example navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu" aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="toggleMobileMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="crew.html">Crew</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="flights.html">Flights</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="events.html">Events</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you want to see my current project live, here you go: [sample](https://geffgames.com/sample)

Comment: IMHO the easiest way to do it would be the use of `PHP include` if the server supports PHP. Othewise you can use iframes. alternativly, you have to create those elements through JS

Comment: @tacoshy How would I create the elements in JS? Could you point me in the right direction? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of browser support you need you could use a template literal (back ticks) to define your navigation. Then use insertAdjacentHTML to place it where you need it on all your html pages.  If your page is fairly simple you could just insert the nav after begin on the body tag.

```js
const navigation = `
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
    <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu"
        aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-label="Toggle Navigation"
        >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="toggleMobileMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
                <a class="nav-link" href="crew.html">Crew</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
                <a class="nav-link" href="flights.html">Flights</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
                <a class="nav-link" href="events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
`
document.getElementById("nav-container").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', navigation);
```

```html
<div id="nav-container"></div>
```

Comment: While you were probably typing this, I took @tacoshy's hint and found this page: [hint](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/)

Comment: JS contents: const header = document.getElementById('header');
header.innerHTML = `<nav>...</nav> then I just have <div id="header"></div> on my page. Turned out I was just making it super complicated. K.I.S.S.

Comment: @GeoffCox HTML templates and custom components are defiantly a really good option.  It will come down to what browsers/versions you are trying to support. I suggest doing some research here: https://caniuse.com/

Comment: using bootstrap5. a lot of the other solutions using the script function.load replacement didn't work, but this worked for me! thanks